# OWL inference using inJena equinox osgi

Tags: java, osgi, jena

im new to OSGI, i wish to know how i can implement OWL inference using Jena in Equinox OSGi Framework. Can i just use the jena.jar and how? My ontology is stored as an OWL file.

i tried incorporating my inference code into the onStartbundle() method but it gives runtime errors.

```
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {

            String sourceURL = "com/my/serviceorchestration/ontology/test.owl";
            String namespace = sourceURL + "#";

            OntModel base = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM );
            base.read( sourceURL, "RDF/XML" );

            OntModel inf = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF, base );

            OntClass deviceClass = base.getOntClass( namespace + "Device" );
            Individual device = base.createIndividual( namespace + "Device1", deviceClass );

            System.out.println("---- Assertions in the data ----");
            for (Iterator<Resource> i = device.listRDFTypes(false); i.hasNext(); ) {
                System.out.println( device.getURI() + " is a " + i.next() );
            }

            System.out.println("\n---- Inferred assertions ----");
            device = inf.getIndividual( namespace + "device1" );
            for (Iterator<Resource> i = device.listRDFTypes(false); i.hasNext(); ) {
                System.out.println( device.getURI() + " is a " + i.next() );
            }
        }
```

here is part of the runtime error log

```
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

thanks for the assistance